# How do I convert a property in MongoDB from text to date type?

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB, I have a document with a field called `"ClockInTime"` that was imported from CSV as a string.

What does an appropriate `db.ClockTime.update()` statement look like to convert these text based values to a date datatype?

Comment: I would like to execute this statement in the Mongo shell as an in-place update.

Comment: would of been good to see some sample data i.e.  "ClockTime" : "-233744483733"

Answer (score 86, accepted):

This code should do it:

```
> var cursor = db.ClockTime.find()
> while (cursor.hasNext()) {
... var doc = cursor.next();
... db.ClockTime.update({_id : doc._id}, {$set : {ClockInTime : new Date(doc.ClockInTime)}})
... }
```

Comment: @Kristina - Phew, this saved a ton of my time and thanks to the author for asking such question.

Comment: Just as a side-note (and I stand to be corrected) but if you're converting from a time stamp value, a string won't work. It has to be a long int. For example a time stamp value of 206281199529 cannot be '206281199529' in the source file (CSV or JSON). I'm not sure why not - tried it out with v2.2.2 and every time it set the date to epoch.

Comment: @Crungmungus that's true, only dates in the form that the date constructor takes will be converted properly.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date for all formats.

Comment: @kristina I have a date in this string format "2003-10-24". I used the above code but all the dates got changed to 1970-01-01.... How I can use the Update function ?

Comment: @Shubham you have to have a valid JavaScript date format, check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date.

Answer (score 14):

I have exactly the same situation as Jeff Fritz.

In my case I have succeed with the following simpler solution:

```
db.ClockTime.find().forEach(function(doc) { 
    doc.ClockInTime=new Date(doc.ClockInTime);
    db.ClockTime.save(doc); 
    })
```

Answer (score 5):

This is a generic sample code in python using pymongo

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
from datetime import datetime

def fixTime(host, port, database, collection, attr, date_format):
    #host is where the mongodb is hosted eg: "localhost"
    #port is the mongodb port eg: 27017
    #database is the name of database eg : "test"
    #collection is the name of collection eg : "test_collection"
    #attr is the column name which needs to be modified
    #date_format is the format of the string eg : "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"
    #http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior
    client = MongoClient(host, port)
    db = client[database]
    col = db[collection]
    for obj in col.find():
        if obj[attr]:
            if type(obj[attr]) is not datetime:
                time = datetime.strptime(obj[attr],date_format)
                col.update({'_id':obj['_id']},{'$set':{attr : time}})
```

for more info : http://salilpa.com/home/content/how-convert-property-mongodb-text-date-type-using-pymongo

Answer (score 4):

Starting `Mongo 4.x`:

- [`db.collection.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/index.html#db.collection.update) can accept an aggregation pipeline, finally allowing the update of a field based on its current value (`Mongo 4.2+`).
- There is a new [`$toDate`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDate/#exp._S_toDate) aggregation operator (`Mongo 4.0`).

Such that:

```
// { a: "2018-03-03" }
db.collection.updateMany(
  {},
  [{ $set: { a: { $toDate: "$a" } } }]
)
// { a: ISODate("2018-03-03T00:00:00Z") }
```

- The first part `{}` is the match query, filtering which documents to update (in this case all documents).
- The second part `[{ $set: { a: { $toDate: "$a" } } }]` is the update aggregation pipeline (note the squared brackets signifying the use of an aggregation pipeline). [`$set`](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/operator/aggregation/set/#pipe._S_set) is a new aggregation operator which in this case replaces the field's value. The replaced value being the field itself concerted to an `ISODate` object. Note how `a` is modified directly based on its own value (`$a`).

Comment: This is the best answer (actually the only correct one) and had zero upvotes :O
You can also use `updateMany`:
`db.collection.updateMany(
    {},
    [{ $set: { a: { $toDate: "$a" } } }]
  )`

Comment: This is a life-saver solution... didn't believe it would work until I tried it out myself.

Comment: Such a simple and straight-forward answer and solution, thanks a-lot! I almost thought Mongo couldn't achieve this simple task so this saved my day!

Answer (score 1):

If you need to check if the field already has been converted you can use this condition:

```
/usr/bin/mongo mydb --eval 'db.mycollection.find().forEach(function(doc){
    if (doc.date instanceof Date !== true) {
        doc.date = new ISODate(doc.date);
        db.mycollection.save(doc);
    }
});'
```

Otherwise the command line may break.