# Find objects between two dates MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, datetime, twitter, mongodb-query

I've been playing around storing tweets inside mongodb, each object looks like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("4c02c58de500fe1be1000005"),
"contributors" : null,
"text" : "Hello world",
"user" : {
    "following" : null,
    "followers_count" : 5,
    "utc_offset" : null,
    "location" : "",
    "profile_text_color" : "000000",
    "friends_count" : 11,
    "profile_link_color" : "0000ff",
    "verified" : false,
    "protected" : false,
    "url" : null,
    "contributors_enabled" : false,
    "created_at" : "Sun May 30 18:47:06 +0000 2010",
    "geo_enabled" : false,
    "profile_sidebar_border_color" : "87bc44",
    "statuses_count" : 13,
    "favourites_count" : 0,
    "description" : "",
    "notifications" : null,
    "profile_background_tile" : false,
    "lang" : "en",
    "id" : 149978111,
    "time_zone" : null,
    "profile_sidebar_fill_color" : "e0ff92"
},
"geo" : null,
"coordinates" : null,
"in_reply_to_user_id" : 149183152,
"place" : null,
"created_at" : "Sun May 30 20:07:35 +0000 2010",
"source" : "web",
"in_reply_to_status_id" : {
    "floatApprox" : 15061797850
},
"truncated" : false,
"favorited" : false,
"id" : {
    "floatApprox" : 15061838001
}
```

How would I write a query which checks the *created_at* and finds all objects between 18:47 and 19:00? Do I need to update my documents so the dates are stored in a specific format?

Comment: You don't say about which field you want query ?

Comment: Oops, I want to query the created_at and find all between two dates.

Comment: I am curious that why not use timestamp, any advantages by using of the Date Obj?

Comment: @Leo The biggest advantage with the Date object over milliseconds since the epoch or whatever is human readability. In this case, setting your start range to `2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z` is much easier than calculating the same date/time in milliseconds. You can also do time zone conversion pretty easily. Also, Dates already handle things like leap days, leap seconds, and other oddities that you usually don't want to handle yourself.

Answer (score 839, accepted):

<strike>[Querying for a Date Range (Specific Month or Day)](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/)</strike> in the <strike>[MongoDB Cookbook](http://cookbook.mongodb.org/)</strike> has a very good explanation on the matter, but below is something I tried out myself and it seems to work.

```
items.save({
    name: "example",
    created_at: ISODate("2010-04-30T00:00:00.000Z")
})
items.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
=> { "_id" : ObjectId("4c0791e2b9ec877893f3363b"), "name" : "example", "created_at" : "Sun May 30 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)" }
```

Based on my experiments you will need to serialize your dates into a format that MongoDB supports, because the following gave undesired search results.

```
items.save({
    name: "example",
    created_at: "Sun May 30 18.49:00 +0000 2010"
})
items.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte:"Mon May 30 18:47:00 +0000 2015",
        $lt: "Sun May 30 20:40:36 +0000 2010"
    }
})
=> { "_id" : ObjectId("4c079123b9ec877893f33638"), "name" : "example", "created_at" : "Sun May 30 18.49:00 +0000 2010" }
```

In the second example no results were expected, but there was still one gotten. This is because a basic string comparison is done.

Comment: Looks interesting, but does the stored date need to be in a specific format. I've just been storing what was provided by twitter, does this need to be changed into a different format?

Comment: You've probably stored the timestamps as strings, so I am guessing MongoDB won't realize that they are in fact dates. Thus doing a range query on them would result in an alphabetical range query (e.g. "Jan Mon 01.01.2010" being before "Jan Sun 01.01.1000"). It would probably make sense to format all date data into the MongoDB format, which I think is just plain JavaScript Date.

Comment: I just used this to convert my strings to date objects http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900674/how-do-i-convert-a-property-in-mongodb-from-text-to-date-type

Comment: Okay cool! I'd guess the range queries mentioned in the cookbook should work then, did you try them out already?

Comment: Yep once I was storing the dates correct the cookbook examples worked as expected.

Comment: If the date is store as string (it's very common) then you should be able to extract the string, converted to DateTime `new Date(dt_field);` and stored in a temporal JavaScript array with a `mongo_collection.foreach()` and `array.push()` and then query that array. NOTE: use temporal mongo table/documents for large amount of data.

Comment: What should i do if i want to use a variable instead of a hard coded date
for e.g. instead of

 'created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-04-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2010-05-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }'

I am using a date filter and want something like :

'created_at: {
        $gte: from_date,
        $lt: to_date
    }'
but my query is defined inside a meteor helper and my variables are created inside template events (I am using Meteorjs by the way).

Answer (score 50):

To clarify. What is important to know is that:

- Yes, you have to pass a Javascript Date object.
- Yes, it has to be ISODate friendly
- Yes, from my experience getting this to work, you need to manipulate the date to ISO
- Yes, working with dates is generally always a tedious process, and mongo is no exception

Here is a working snippet of code, where we do a little bit of date manipulation to ensure Mongo (here i am using mongoose module and want results for rows whose date attribute is less than (before) the date given as myDate param) can handle it correctly:

```
var inputDate = new Date(myDate.toISOString());
MyModel.find({
    'date': { $lte: inputDate }
})
```

Comment: Plus one for clarity. If your using moment in the backend, it still retains the toISOString() function. I use moment to add and subtract time for my queries.

Comment: I think it should read: var inputDate = new Date(myDate).toISOString();

Answer (score 31):

## Python and `pymongo`

Finding objects between two dates in Python with `pymongo` in collection `posts` (based on the [tutorial](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html#range-queries)):

```
from_date = datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 31, 12, 30, 30, 125000)
to_date = datetime.datetime(2011, 12, 31, 12, 30, 30, 125000)

for post in posts.find({"date": {"$gte": from_date, "$lt": to_date}}):
    print(post)
```

Where `{"$gte": from_date, "$lt": to_date}` specifies the range in terms of `datetime.datetime` types.

Comment: This is not working. Whenever I run this query I get by default complete response and not filtered response

Comment: This is not working. I tried with python3 and it gets no results back

Answer (score 23):

```
db.collection.find({"createdDate":{$gte:new ISODate("2017-04-14T23:59:59Z"),$lte:new ISODate("2017-04-15T23:59:59Z")}}).count();
```

Replace `collection` with name of collection you want to execute query

Comment: @DanDascalescu -may be it did not add anything 
but what is your concern here ?

Comment: Duplicate answers waste people's time.

Comment: @DanDascalescu - then don't waste time , do something productive.

Answer (score 21):

MongoDB actually stores the millis of a date as an int(64), as prescribed by http://bsonspec.org/#/specification

However, it can get pretty confusing when you retrieve dates as the client driver will instantiate a date object with its own local timezone. The JavaScript driver in the mongo console will certainly do this.

So, if you care about your timezones, then make sure you know what it's supposed to be when you get it back. This shouldn't matter so much for the queries, as it will still equate to the same int(64), regardless of what timezone your date object is in (I hope). But I'd definitely make queries with actual date objects (not strings) and let the driver do its thing.

Answer (score 16):

**Using with [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) and [Comparison Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)**

```
  var today = moment().startOf('day');
  // "2018-12-05T00:00:00.00
  var tomorrow = moment(today).endOf('day');
  // ("2018-12-05T23:59:59.999

  Example.find(
  {
    // find in today
    created: { '$gte': today, '$lte': tomorrow }
    // Or greater than 5 days
    // created: { $lt: moment().add(-5, 'days') },
  }), function (err, docs) { ... });
```

Answer (score 15):

Use this code to find the record between two dates using `$gte` and `$lt`:

```
db.CollectionName.find({"whenCreated": {
    '$gte': ISODate("2018-03-06T13:10:40.294Z"),
    '$lt': ISODate("2018-05-06T13:10:40.294Z")
}});
```

Comment: What does this add to the accepted answer, provided 8 years earlier?

Answer (score 12):

Save created_at date in ISO Date Format then use $gte and $lte.

```
db.connection.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2010-05-30T18:47:00.000Z"),
        $lte: ISODate("2010-05-30T19:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 10):

```
db.collection.find({$and:
  [
    {date_time:{$gt:ISODate("2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z")}},
     {date_time:{$lt:ISODate("2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z")}}
   ]
 })

##In case you are making the query directly from your application ##

db.collection.find({$and:
   [
     {date_time:{$gt:"2020-06-01T00:00:00.000Z"}},
     {date_time:{$lt:"2020-06-30T00:00:00.000Z"}}
  ]

 })
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also check this out. If you are using this method, then use the parse function to get values from Mongo Database:

```
db.getCollection('user').find({
    createdOn: {
        $gt: ISODate("2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2020-03-01T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 6):

use **$gte** and **$lte** to find between date data's in mongodb

```
var tomorrowDate = moment(new Date()).add(1, 'days').format("YYYY-MM-DD");
db.collection.find({"plannedDeliveryDate":{ $gte: new Date(tomorrowDate +"T00:00:00.000Z"),$lte: new Date(tomorrowDate + "T23:59:59.999Z")}})
```

Comment: Slight typo in your answer $gte not $get :)

Comment: Sorry i answered very tired condition, so i made mistake. Thanks for your help to update my answer. you did good job :) @Bob

Answer (score 6):

```
mongoose.model('ModelName').aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            userId: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId)
        }
    },
    {
        $project: {
            dataList: {
              $filter: {
                 input: "$dataList",
                 as: "item",
                 cond: { 
                    $and: [
                        {
                            $gte: [ "$$item.dateTime", new Date(`2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`) ]
                        },
                        {
                            $lte: [ "$$item.dateTime", new Date(`2019-12-01T00:00:00.000Z`) ]
                        },
                    ]
                 }
              }
           }
        }
     }
])
```

Answer (score 5):

For those using **Make (formerly Integromat) and MongoDB**:
I was struggling to find the right way to query all records between two dates. In the end, all I had to do was to **remove `ISODate`** as suggested in some of the solutions here.

So the full code would be:

```
"created": {
    "$gte": "2016-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
    "$lt": "2017-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"
}
```

This [article](https://www.integromat.com/en/help/app/mongodb#:%7E:text=allowing%20%25.integromat.com.-,Date/time%20queries,-To%20perform%20a) helped me achieve my goal.

---

**UPDATE**

Another way to achieve the above code in **Make** (formerly Integromat) would be to use the [parseDate](https://www.integromat.com/en/help/date-time-functions#:%7E:text=parseDate%20(text%3B%20format%3B%20%5Btimezone%5D)) function. So the code below will return the same result as the one above :

```
"created": {
    "$gte": "{{parseDate("2016-01-01"; "YYYY-MM-DD")}}",
    "$lt": "{{parseDate("2017-01-01"; "YYYY-MM-DD")}}"
}
```

⚠️ Be sure to wrap `{{parseDate("2017-01-01"; "YYYY-MM-DD")}}` between quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

Convert your dates to GMT timezone as you're stuffing them into Mongo.  That way there's never a timezone issue.  Then just do the math on the twitter/timezone field when you pull the data back out for presentation.

Answer (score 3):

Why not convert the string to an integer of the form YYYYMMDDHHMMSS?  Each increment of time would then create a larger integer, and you can filter on the integers instead of worrying about converting to ISO time.

Comment: Because time isn't just happening in my local timezone.

Comment: This becomes a nightmare once you start having to convert the time to and from that format everywhere. If you're going to do something like this at the very least use the return value from .getTime() from a JS date object.

Comment: thats why we always store data in UTC

Answer (score 1):

Scala:
With joda DateTime and BSON syntax (reactivemongo):

```
val queryDateRangeForOneField = (start: DateTime, end: DateTime) =>
    BSONDocument(
      "created_at" -> BSONDocument(
        "$gte" -> BSONDateTime(start.millisOfDay().withMinimumValue().getMillis), 
        "$lte" -> BSONDateTime(end.millisOfDay().withMaximumValue().getMillis)),
     )
```

where `millisOfDay().withMinimumValue()` for "2021-09-08T06:42:51.697Z" will be "2021-09-08T00:00:00.000Z"
and
where `millisOfDay(). withMaximumValue()` for "2021-09-08T06:42:51.697Z" will be "2021-09-08T23:59:99.999Z"

Answer (score 0):

i tried in this model as per my requirements i need to store a date when ever a  object is created later i want to retrieve all the records (documents ) between two dates
 in my html file
i was using the following format mm/dd/yyyy

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">

<html>
<head>

    <script>
//jquery
    $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("#select_date").click(function() { 
    $.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "xxx", 
    datatype: "html",
    data: $("#period").serialize(),  
    success: function(data){
    alert(data);
    } ,//success

    }); //event triggered

    });//ajax
    });//jquery  
    </script>

    <title></title>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="period" name='period'>
        from <input id="selecteddate" name="selecteddate1" type="text"> to 
        <input id="select_date" type="button" value="selected">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

in my py (python) file i converted it into "iso fomate"
in following way

```
date_str1   = request.POST["SelectedDate1"] 
SelectedDate1   = datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str1, '%m/%d/%Y').isoformat()
```

and saved in my dbmongo collection with "SelectedDate" as field in my collection

to retrieve data or documents  between to 2 dates i used following query

```
db.collection.find( "SelectedDate": {'$gte': SelectedDate1,'$lt': SelectedDate2}})
```