# MongoDB count aggregate per month

Tags: mongodb

Is there a way to get the total number of documents in a MongoDB database by months (for example, so I can display a chart showing the evolution of the number of users) in a single request? or should I request each month individually?

I don't want to see the number of users created in a month but the total (this month + previous months).

Comment: Use the [db.collection.count()](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.count/) method e.g `db.users.count( { created_dt: { $gt: new Date('01/07/2014') } } )`

Comment: Do you have any field in the document that stores the creation date?  Can you share a sample document from your collection?

Comment: Please give u example documents and show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

Each document in the collection has a field representing the date it was created.
To get the total number of documents in a MongoDB database by months, use a range query to query for documents whose value for created_on is greater than a Date representing the start of the month, and less than a Date representing the end.

Assume the start date is 'start' and the end date is 'end'. Then the query will be,

db.users.count({created_on: {$gte: start, $lt: end}});

Here is a nice explanation relevant to this topic. 
http://cookbook.mongodb.org/patterns/date_range/

Refer the answers in this thread also.
[Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)