# Between dates query in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying query between two dates in MongoDB but I'm not getting anything back but I do have the correct data. I'm thinking that the date format might be wrong. Is it correct?

This is the query that I'm running

```
  { '$gte': Sun Feb 01 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST),
      '$lt': Tue Mar 03 2015 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (IST) }
```

and my JS query code looks like this

```
query.created = {$gte:new Date(this.props.startDate), $lt:new Date(this.props.endDate)};
```

Comment: did you check [this SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)?

Comment: @Ethaan no going over it now looks like the wrong format thanks

Comment: Be careful not to mix up the mongo shell and meteor here... The JS code you posted doesn't look bad (Meteor uses the JS `Date` object everywhere). I don't understand what the first object is  (it's not even valid JSON)..

Comment: @mnemosyn is the console.log for the query created

Answer (score 5):

Mongo recognizes the ISODate type. It can be used to make common date-related queries (like the one you're trying to do).

So it should be something like this:

```
{ '$gte': ISODate(01-02-2015T02:00:00Z),
  '$lt': ISODate(03-03-2015T02:00:00Z) }
```

Please read further [this](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/shell-types/) documentation for more details.

Also, check out [this](https://university.mongodb.com/) link to the oficial online courses, there is a section where it cover your problem.

Comment: AFAIK, `ISODate` is part of the mongo console and isn't known to Meteor

Comment: Woa! I didn't see the meteor tag, sorry about that, like you're saying, this answer was to deal with the mongo console. Should I delete the answer?

Answer (score 2):

```
db.collection.find({
    created_at: {
        $gte: ISODate("2015-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2015-03-03T00:00:00.000Z")
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use [twix.js](https://atmospherejs.com/momentjs/twix) and publish my collection for responses in an array that match my date-range condition.