# How to find date between stat date and end date

Tags: mongodb, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I have two fields in database start_date and end_date.
How to find if date which i am passing is in between these two dates.

Model

```
class Schedule
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :start_date, type: Date
  field :end_date, type: Date

end
```

Simple activerecord query would be

```
Schedule.where(["start_date <= ? AND end_date >= ?", params[:date], params[:date] ])
```

Date is saved in database in following format

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("559d182f6368611dbf000000"),
"start_date" : ISODate("2015-06-10T00:00:00.000Z"),
"end_date" : ISODate("2015-07-10T00:00:00.000Z")
```

}

and my parameter contain date like "2015-06-10"

What will be the query while using MongoDB database with Mongoid?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: @BlakesSeven: this is higher level access, though.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Said "Mongoid" which can use the same principles. Still don't see the justification for another duplicate question though. Search engines work.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: can use, yes, but mongoid-native method is better.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Translation of a string taking CPU cycles is better? We have different learning principles. Anyhow I'm talking to the OP now saying "your date argument is a string" you need to supply an Object that casts to a `Date` than can be serialized to a BSON query.

Comment: @BlakesSeven: date parsing must happen anyway and CPU cycles will be burned. These things being equal, it's better to have nicer code :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev "nicer" to read does not equal "nicer" performance. You seem to fighting a loosing war here to justify your answer and presuming that a lower rep score means less knowlege. I don't see how this is productive. Your answer is either accepted or not. Either way my opinion is the question does not need to be here as it is clearly documented elsewere.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82711/discussion-between-sergio-tulentsev-and-blakes-seven).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work

```
 Schedule.where(:start_date.lte => date, :end_date.gte => date)
```

Comment: Thanks for the right answer, next time i will surely do more search about question, before posting it..