# A PHP program to get the count of month from a collection in MongoDB database

Tags: php, mongodb

In mongodb I am trying to fetch the count of month from a collection which holds the field in the format of ISO Date..

> ISODate("2015-05-18T03:56:07.030Z")

retrived the date format as

> 2015-Jun-17 06:59:33

From that , how do i get the count of month from (January to december from ISO Date) from the collection using mongodb  query..

I just need count of month from a collection.

colud some one suggest some ideas for this issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Comment: i just exploded the Date and retrived the month separetly struggling to put mongodb query to obtain the count of month.

Comment: am not trying to fetch the objects between two dates am just trying to fetch the count of month  from january  to december.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand you want to get month count without duplications, so you can use [$group](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) of *aggregation framework*.

For examle if in your collection name of ISODate field is `date`, the query can be something like this:

```
db.COLLECTION_NAME.aggregate(
   [
      {
        $group : {
           _id : { month: { $month: "$date" } },
           monthCount: { $sum: 1 }
        }
      }
   ]
)
```

Comment: Thankyou for your valuable response..How do i fetch the records from collection by monthwise using  "PHP with mongodb"..could  you suggest me some example  query..that  would be great helpful  for me.

Comment: @kothai Sorry, but I not understand your question, what means "monthwise" ?

Comment: @kothai Please see this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-month-day-and-year

Comment: Thank you for the documentation .. It works!!!..I just  implemented it in putty which shows  the correct output...how do i implement  it with "PHP and mongodb".
how do i reformat the shell command for my " PHP with MongoDB".??

Comment: @kothai You need to install PHP driver for Mongo: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver#installing-on-windows
      
And than learn how to use.
       
official PHP tutorial: http://php.net/manual/en/mongo.tutorial.php
      
other tutorials: http://www.sitepoint.com/building-simple-blog-app-mongodb-php/ 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_php.htm