# how to get data between two dates in Mongo?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON format like below:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "566acc776cc532d5368db0f5",
    "date": "2015-12-01T13:02:30.720Z",
    "title1": "title"
  }
]
```

Need some nodejs query that returns data between two dates.
I also tried in find query `object` as follow but get nothing. How to match please tell me.

```
{ 
   date: { 
       $gte:ISODate("2013-11-19T14:00:00Z"), 
       $lt: ISODate("2013-11-19T20:00:00Z") 
   } 
}
```

Some ISODate Error. Please give me a suggestion.

Comment: Can you paste in your error? Since I am trying your code in mongo console and not getting any error

Comment: You reference here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, **solved!!** . Get it. I just need to remove `ISODate` string.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you do like this to resolve the Issue.

```
    // Fetch Document By Current Date
    const startDate =new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString();
    const endDate =new Date(new Date().setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999)).toISOString();
    
    // Fetch Document By Specific Date (findDate is Parameter)
 const startDate =new Date(new Date(findDate).setUTCHours(0, 0, 0, 0)).toISOString();
    const endDate =new Date(new Date(findDate).setUTCHours(23, 59, 59, 999)).toISOString();

   let result = yourModel.find({date: { 
       $gte:`${startDate}`, 
       $lt: `${endDate}` 
   } })
```