# Time Find query in Mongodb in format "09:14"

Tags: mongodb

I have inserted time in mongodb collection in this format, "09:68". Now I want to write a find query using time and unable to write on. Can anyone tell me any solution without modifying my database?

Data Format is below,

```
"dep_timing":[{"time": "09:50"}, 
 {"time": "11:50"},
 {"time": "12:50"},
 {"time": "13:50"},
 {"time": "14:50"},
 {"time": "15:50"},
 {"time": "16:50"},
 {"time": "17:50"},
 {"time": "18:50"},
 {"time": "19:50"}, 
 {"time": "20:50"},
 {"time": "21:50"},
 {"time": "22:55"}],
```

Tested Queries:

```
>db.east.find({"dep.dep_timing.time":{$gte:05}});
>db.east.find({"dep.dep_timing.time":{$gte:10}});
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Check this SO link [Find between two dates in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb).
You need to provide the date format in a way which MongoDB understands.

Answer (score 0):

I tried below query and it is working fine.

```
>db.east.find({"dep.dep_timing.time":{$gte:"05:10"}});
```