# Running prepared mongodb queries using Java driver

Tags: java, mongodb

I am having trouble formatting the query below for it to be parse-able by the JSON utility provided by [MongoDB Java driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/) and I'd like suggestions. First, some context.

A test framework, at the end of every run, stores the test results in MongoDB.
Here are 2 such samples from collection 'TestResults':

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("SomeId#1"),
        "_class" : "com.example.dao.entity.TestResults",
        "testScenario" : "Test login",
        "runId" : 314,
        "runDate" : ISODate("2016-12-14T15:51:04.586Z"),
        "status" : "passed"
}

{
        "_id" : ObjectId("SomeId#2"),
        "_class" : "com.example.dao.entity.TestResults",
        "testScenario" : "Test reset password",
        "runId" : 314,
        "runDate" : ISODate("2016-12-14T20:50:01.269Z"),
        "status" : "passed"
}
```

And, another collection called 'Queries' contains pre-written query templates. The query below `find`s Documents by `runDate`:

```
{
        "_id": ObjectId("SomeId#3"),
        "_class": "com.example.dao.entity.Query",
        "query": "{\"runDate\":{\"$gte\":new Date(\"%1$s\"),\"$lt\":new Date(\"%2$s\")}}"
}
```

The intent is to use the above query template, after adding a valid time range, on the aforementioned 'testResults' collection and process further. Here's what I've tried so far:

**Using JSON.parse()**:

```
LocalDateTime dateTime1=LocalDateTime.of(2016, 12, 14, 00, 00,00);
LocalDateTime dateTime2 = dateTime1.plusHours(24);

/* Gets date range query from  'Queries' collection */
String dateRange = getDateRangeQuery(); 
/* Apply time range for last 24 hours... */
dateRange = String.format(dateRange,dateTime1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME),dateTime2.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE_TIME));

BasicDBObject dayQuery=(BasicDBObject) JSON.parse(dateRange);
FindIterable<Document> result = database.getCollection("testResults").find(dayQuery);
result.forEach(new Block<Document>() {

    @Override
    public void apply(Document t) {
        System.out.println("QUERY RESULT:"+t.toJson());

    }
});
```

On running, JSON.parse() throws this exception

```
 com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException: 
{"runDate":{"$gte":new Date("2016-12-14T00:00:00"),"$lt":new Date("2016-12-15T00:00:00")}}
           ^    
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.read(JSON.java:301)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:172)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:263)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:227)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parseObject(JSON.java:263)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:227)
at com.mongodb.util.JSONParser.parse(JSON.java:155)
at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:92)
at com.mongodb.util.JSON.parse(JSON.java:73)
```

**Using BsonDocument.parse()**:

`BsonDocument.parse()` was able to parse the query but I couldn't find a way to configure the collection name for the `BsonDocument` to be then used in `MongoDatabase.runCommand()`

So now what are my options ?

Comment: The query matches the ones found in [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2943222/531762). I've also tried it on my own data and it seems to work for me in RoboMongo. So that doesn't look like the source of the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to update query template to a compatible JSON type so it can be parsed.

Query Template Json:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("SomeId#3"),
    "_class": "com.example.dao.entity.Query",
    "query": "{"runDate":{ "$gte" :{"date" : { "$date" : "%1$s"}}}}"
}
```

Code:

```
Instant dateTime = Instant.now();
String dateRange = String.format(getDateRangeQuery(),dateTime.toString()));
```

Now you can run this as a regular query after `JSON.parse()`.

More here on other types:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/mongodb-extended-json/

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the new Date syntax is not supported in the query, but only in the internal Javascript libraries.

For the query, replace "new Date" with "ISODate" (e.g. ISODate("2017-01-10T10:13:58.630Z") ) and it should be working.