# Yii2 mongodb activerecord find by date (YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: mongodb, yii2

In mongodb ***created_on*** values is like ***YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s*** *e.g 2017-08-03 11:51:05*. but while searching outputs i have to pass only date ***YYYY-mm-dd*** but it is not working with Yii2 mongodb activerecord but it is working from terminal.

**Mongodb activerecord :**

```
$output  = DeviceOutput::find()
                ->where(["created_on"=>"/^$date/"])
                ->one();
```

**Terminal Command :**

```
db.device_output.find({"created_on":/^2017-08-03/})
```

How to do it in PHP ?

Comment: It's "much better" to actually convert the "strings" to a BSON Date and then [use a "range" to select between the dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb) ( a single day is in fact a "range" ). Stored as a BSON Date, this in fact takes **4-bytes** ( length of the long integer value for the timestamp ) as compared to the **24-bytes** to store the "string". Not only does storage take more space, but that also equates to time to load and process, and it's a significant difference, especially over a large amount of data.

Comment: That said, your query fails because you are constructing a "string" rather than a "regular expression" like what is actually being done in the shell. Either create a valid regular expression or use the `$regex` BSON expression. But **ideally** ( and realistically ) you really should fix the dates from being strings in the first place.

Comment: @NeilLunn can you give me example how should i do in php mongodb / yii2 mongodb activerecord?