# Getting a list of items from mongodb with the date of today

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

I would like to get a list of items with the date of today from my MongoDB. I only get the result I want when I hard code the date: `"date":"2017-10-26T07:09:36.417Z` in my `pushups.js` file below.

Here is my code.

Documents in my MongoDB

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "59f18ac290531423ecb3cb51"
    },
    "date": "2017-10-26T07:09:36.417Z",
    "count": "25"
}
```

**`pushups.js`**:

```js
router.get("/pushupsToday", function (req, res) {
var dateObj = new Date();
console.log(dateObj);

db.pushups.find({"date": dateObj}, function (err, pushups) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
    res.status(200).send({"success": true, "result": pushups});
});
```

**`pushups.service.ts`**:

```typescript
@Injectable()
export class PushupService {

  apiUrl = this.appSettings.getApiURL();
  data;
  removedItemId;
  removedItem;

  constructor(public http: Http, public appSettings: AppSettings) {

  }

  public getTodays() {
    return this.http
               .get(this.apiUrl + 'api/pushupsToday')
               .map(response => response.json().result);
  }
```

**`home.ts`**:

```typescript
getTodays() {
  console.log("getTodays in home.ts");
  this.pushupSeriesToday = this.pushupService.getTodays();
}
```

**`home.html`**:

```html
<ion-item *ngFor="let item of pushupSeriesToday | async ">
  <ion-item>{{item.count}} - {{item.date | date}}</ion-item>
</ion-item>
```

Comment: A "day" is actually the "range" of possible values between "start of today" and "tomorrow".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use moment js to change the format of your date before saving it to your database.

```
var currentDate = moment(new Date()).format('MM-DD-YYYY');
```

so you can easily filter it.

Comment: That won't work and there is a very good reason why. [Read the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb) and understand.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. I used moment.js and Here is how I solved it:   
    var currentDate = moment(new Date()).format("YYYY-MM-DD");
    var currentDateS = currentDate + "T00:00:00:000Z";
    var currentDateE = currentDate + "T23:59:59:000Z"; 
    db.pushups.find({"date": {$gte: currentDateS, $lt: currentDateE}},

Comment: @MrTots Glad i could help.