# Filter and range operations on pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

I have a Mongo database having below values in a collection test

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905bb59c92d93d9072c781"), "par1" : 123, "par2" : 777, "par3" : 45 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905bdc9c92d93d9072c782"), "par1" : 124, "par2" : 787, "par3" : 46 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905be59c92d93d9072c783"), "par1" : 125, "par2" : 787, "par3" : 47 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905c039c92d93d9072c784"), "par1" : 12, "par2" : 453, "par3" : 48 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905c1c9c92d93d9072c785"), "par1" : 12, "par2" : 453, "par3" : 49 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905c219c92d93d9072c786"), "par1" : 12, "par2" : 453, "par3" : 50 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905c489c92d93d9072c787"), "par1" : 124, "par2" : 787, "par3" : 46 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5a905d339c92d93d9072c788"), "par1" : 124, "par2" : 787, "par3" : 54 }
```

using pymongo can we do the say filter and range operation in one query and get all the entries corresponding to range and filter.
e.g:
filter for par1 = 124 and par2 = 787 within the range for par3 = 45 to 54

I tried incorporating aggregate but was unsuccessful.
thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

Suppose range implies one exclusive of the upper bound, operator expressions for 'par3' field can be combined.

If you'll like to include the upper bound, use `lte` comparison operator instead of `lt` comparison operator.

```
query = {'par1': 124, 'par2': 787, 'par3': {'$gte':45, '$lt': 54}}
cur = collection.find(query)
print(list(cur))
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. i have tried the code and it is working