# Search MongoDB collection when date is stored as timestamp

Tags: mongodb, search, timestamp, isodate

I'm new to MongoDB. I have a collection which has a field named **time** in it. It's in **timestamp** format like this:

```
{
        "_id" : "uniqueid_001",
        "customer_id" : 1234567,
        "time" : 1513300298028,
        "price" : 1000,
        "action" : "buy"
}
```

Now I would like to only retrieve documents between a date range. I've used something like this:

```
db.sales.find({
     time: {
          $gt: ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00.000Z")/1000,
          $lt: ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00.000Z")/1000
     } 
})
```

But this won't work. Anyone has any idea that how may I achieve this?

Thanks

P.S. This question is somehow answered here: [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb) but there's a difference that date is saved in ISO format on that question but I need to compare dates in timestamp format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops! Find it myself... The timestamp is saved in collection in 13 digits format. It didn't need /1000 instead /1 in the end of ISODate function:

```
db.sales.find({
     time: {
          $gt: ISODate("2018-02-01T00:00.000Z")/1,
          $lt: ISODate("2018-02-10T00:00.000Z")/1
     } 
})
```

Thanks anyway