# Querying MongoDB for date string with C++

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I have a collection of MongoDB documents that look like this:

```
{
  ...
  "doc_date": ISODate("2018-03-29T00:00:00.000Z"),
  ...
}
```

How can I use the C++ (non-legacy) MongoDB API to query for this document given just the date (assuming that the time is always 00:00:00.000)? That is, I would like to do something like:

```
void my_func(std::string date_to_query) {
  auto result = mongo_collection.find_one(document{} 
     << "doc_date" << date_to_query 
     << finalize);  // This obviously doesn't work
  // ...
}
my_func("2018-03-29");
```

What's the right query to find a document in Mongo by date given a date string?

Answer (score 0):

Given the date as a string, convert it to a `std::chrono` type representing the beginning of the day, and from that construct two `bsoncxx::b_date` objects that range over the UNIX time period ranging over that day, then construct a query using `$gt` and `$lt` (adjusted as needed for inclusive/exclusive bounds).

For some examples see: [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

There is probably also a more clever way to do this with the aggregation framework.