# MongoDB/Mongoose querying documents between certain dates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want it to obtain documents between certain dates, I know that I need to use the **$and** operator but right now I'm using [Querymen](https://github.com/diegohaz/querymen), a middleware for MongoDB , I read the documentation but I couldn't find anything related to.

What I'm doing is this:

```
router.get('/',
  token({ required: true }),
  query({
    after: {
      type: Date,
      paths: ['fecha'],
      operator: '$gte'
    },
    before: {
      type: Date,
      paths: ['fecha'],
      operator: '$lte'
    }
  }),
  index)
```

So my question is how to use the $and operator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to use `$and` operator in your query. Instead of this:

```
{
  $and: [
    { yourDateField: { $lte: '2018-08-09' } },
    { yourDateField: { $gte: '2018-08-03' } },
  ]
}
```

you can do:

```
{
  yourDateField: {
    $lte: '2018-08-09',
    $gte: '2018-08-03'
  }
}
```

So you can use this schema for **querymen**:

```
const querySchema = {
  after: {
    type: Date,
    paths: ['yourDateField'],
    operator: '$gte'
  },
  before: {
    type: Date,
    paths: ['yourDateField'],
    operator: '$lte'
  }
};
```

Full example may be looking like this:

```
const querymen = require('querymen');
const app = require('express')();

const querySchema = {
  after: {
    type: Date,
    paths: ['yourDateField'],
    operator: '$gte'
  },
  before: {
    type: Date,
    paths: ['yourDateField'],
    operator: '$lte'
  }
};

app.get('/', querymen.middleware(querySchema), (req, res) => {
  const { querymen: { query } } = req;
  res.json({ ok: true, query });
});

app.listen(8000, () => console.log('Up and running on http://localhost:8000'));
```

If you still in doubt why not use `$and` operator look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943685/6317812).

Comment: thanks, I solved it in a different way but it was messy, your solution is much more elegant and also I did not know that it was not necessary to use the $and operator