# Query MongoDB documents where min and max columns encompass a value

Tags: mongodb, date, range

My documents have the following structure, where `start` and `end` represent hours in the format of `HH:MM`:

```
{_id: 1, start: "11:30", end: "14:30" }
{_id: 2, start: "05:30", end: "11:30" }
{_id: 3, start: "14:30", end: "18:00" }
{_id: 4, start: "18:30", end: "23:59" }
```

I receive another `HH:MM` value. Then, I need to obtain the `_id` of the record where the value I got is between the `start` and `end` range.

For example, if I have the value `15:18`, I will need to obtain `_id = 3`, because `start > 15:18` and `end <= 15:18`.

The examples I've found show the opposite case (having the min/max values and querying which row has a cell between those values). [This is an example](https://vladmihalcea.com/mongodb-time-series-introducing-the-aggregation-framework/), and [this is another example](http://www.tinnedgeek.com/how-to-search-a-mongodb-database-for-entries-between-two-dates-or-times/), and [another one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `$gte` and `$lte` operators inside `.find()` method. Try:

```
db.col.find({ start: { $lte: "15:18" }, end: { $gte: "15:18" } })
```

Comment: The issue is that `start` and `end` are stored as `String`, therefore, I cannot compare them like this.

Comment: @Mel are you sure that simple strings comparison won't be working here ? Could you give me an example when it might fail ?

Comment: I tried the same data of the example, and it didn't work.

Comment: @Mel please take a look here: https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ju6B_RW87ZH