# Is there any query to find data between given dates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, yeoman

I am sending the startDate and endDate in the URL and hits the query to find the data between startDate and endDate

```
var startDate = res.req.query.startDate ? moment(res.req.query.startDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').valueOf() : null
var endDate = res.req.query.endDate ? moment(res.req.query.endDate, 'YYYY-MM-DD').valueOf() : null
if (startDate && endDate) { 
   query.dispatchDate = { $gte:startDate , $lte: endDate }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

You did not clearly asked your question but i am suggestion you a solution what i understand.

In order to find data between 2 dates first you must add a field in db to track when the record is entered let suppose you have a collection named items and field to track when data is enter is created_date then you can find data between 2 dates like

```
items.find({
     created_at: {
          $gte: ISODate("2019-01-21T00:00:00.000Z"),
          $lt: ISODate("2019-01-28T00:00:00.000Z")
     }
})
```

for more details sh[How to find objects between 2 dates in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: dispatchDate is the field in the database on which I perform the query and strartDate and endDate is coming from frontend in the URL and I'm using npm moment to format the date

Comment: You should really be saving dates as Date objects in mongodb not date strings.

Comment: Please do not answer questions that already have answers. Instead, flag the question as a duplicate; [answer].

Comment: @Rafael Thanks for the suggestion i will follow that in future