# How to apply date filter between dates in amcharts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, amcharts

I'm using amcharts4 for my data visualization, using nodejs, mongodb, my problem is how can I filter my charts between dates, using from this date to this date. I'm having a hard time here, nobody is giving me any ideas on how to do this. Here is a sample demo using amcharts 3: https://www.amcharts.com/demos-v3/multiple-data-sets-v3/, any idea is appreciated, I need to finish this for my thesis please somebody give me any idea

```js
initChart();

function initChart(){
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_dark);
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [{
  "date": "2012-09-08",
  "value": 43
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-09",
  "value": 40
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-10",
  "value": 39
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-11",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-12",
  "value": 29
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-13",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-14",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-15",
  "value": 42
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-16",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-17",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-18",
  "value": 47
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-19",
  "value": 55
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-20",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-21",
  "value": 58
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-22",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-23",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-24",
  "value": 59
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-25",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-26",
  "value": 65
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-27",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-28",
  "value": 66
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-29",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-09-30",
  "value": 71
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-01",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-02",
  "value": 63
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-03",
  "value": 46
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-04",
  "value": 32
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-05",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-06",
  "value": 18
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-07",
  "value": 21
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-08",
  "value": 28
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-09",
  "value": 27
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-10",
  "value": 36
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-11",
  "value": 33
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-12",
  "value": 31
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-13",
  "value": 30
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-14",
  "value": 34
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-15",
  "value": 38
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-16",
  "value": 37
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-17",
  "value": 44
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-18",
  "value": 49
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-19",
  "value": 53
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-20",
  "value": 57
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-21",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-22",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-23",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-24",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-25",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-26",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-27",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-29",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-30",
  "value": 70
}];

// Create axes
var dateAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.DateAxis());
dateAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
dateAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 50;

var valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());

// Create series
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.LineSeries());
series.dataFields.valueY = "value";
series.dataFields.dateX = "date";
series.strokeWidth = 3;
series.fillOpacity = 0.5;

// Add vertical scrollbar
chart.scrollbarY = new am4core.Scrollbar();
chart.scrollbarY.marginLeft = 0;

// Add cursor
chart.cursor = new am4charts.XYCursor();
chart.cursor.behavior = "zoomY";
chart.cursor.lineX.disabled = true;

// Create a horizontal scrollbar with previe and place it underneath the date axis
chart.scrollbarX = new am4charts.XYChartScrollbar();
chart.scrollbarX.series.push(series);
chart.scrollbarX.parent = chart.bottomAxesContainer;

chart.events.on("ready", function () {
  dateAxis.zoom({start:0.10, end:1});
});
}
```

```css
body { background-color: #30303d; color: #fff; }
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Resources -->
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/dark.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
```

Comment: when do you want to filter? before creating the chart or after using some button by giving out the dates.

Comment: after the chart is rendered like pressing the button

Comment: but any of the two will be a help, either filter after the chart is rendered or filter the database before rendering the chart

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter by start and end date:

```js
const startDate = new Date("2012-10-25");
const endDate = new Date("2012-10-30");
const data = [{
  "date": "2012-10-21",
  "value": 60
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-22",
  "value": 61
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-23",
  "value": 69
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-24",
  "value": 67
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-25",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-26",
  "value": 77
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-27",
  "value": 75
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-28",
  "value": 70
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-29",
  "value": 72
}, {
  "date": "2012-10-30",
  "value": 70
}]
const filteredData = data.filter(el => new Date(el.date).getTime() >= startDate.getTime() && new Date(el.date) <= endDate.getTime());

console.log(filteredData);
```

Comment: can you apply this using the chart?