# query timestamp in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

In mongodb I have a date field with format like this
`"accessedAt" : "04-25-2018T21:12:53"`

And I am not sure how to query it, I tried

```
db.collection.find({"accessedAt": {"$eq": new Date("04-25-2018T21:12:53")}})

db.collection.find({"accessedAt": {"$eq": ISODate("04-25-2018T21:12:53")}}).
```

Want to retrieve the all the documents that equals today date. Could someone please help me?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb

Comment: It's strange to me. I wonder which data type of the 'accessedAt' field. Could you make a query to show an object information like this:

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d15998a93cd5c2f578dcd9f"),
    "date1" : ISODate("2019-06-28T04:37:30.636Z"),
    "date2" : "Fri Jun 28 2019 11:37:30 GMT+0700 (SE Asia Standard Time)"
}

Comment: Can you please post the answer how to find using var in the script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way :

```
db.collection.find({"accessedAt": {"$eq": ISODate("2018-04-25T21:12:53Z")}});
```

read more here :https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Date/

Comment: The ISO date didn't work Saurabh. And in that link I dont see it how to use it in find query.

Comment: @rviDesai , what you want get , describe in question , Do you want to find record by exact "accessedAt" datetime , then use "$eq" , else use "$gt" to find datetime grater than perticuler datetime , also you can use $lt , $lte , $gt, $gte operators