# how to pass 2 dates to req params to find data between 2 dates

Tags: node.js

*I am creating a rest API for my company for reporting*
*Routs to pass dates to find data from 2 given dates*

```
router.get('/smDcr/:currentDate?&:lastDate:', authorize, getDcrBetweenDates);
```

*Controller action to get the data between dates*

```
exports.getDcrBetweenDates = async(req, res, next) => {
    try{
        const lastDate = req.params.lastDate;
        const currentDate = req.params.currentDate;
        console.log(lastDate);
        const dcr = await Dcr.find({
            where: {
                createdAt: {
                    $between:[currentDate, lastDate]
                }
            }
        });
        if(!dcr) return res.status(400).json({message: "No DCR found between mentioned Dates!!"});
        return res.status(200).json({ dcr});

    }catch(ex){
        next(ex)
    }

}
```

*while passing parameter in postman I am getting all reports not specific to the dates given in params*
*http://localhost:3000/smDcr/?currentDate=2019/09/11&?lastDate=2019/09/11*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need to use $where condition, you just can set your request object inside find function
2. I think you should use $gte and $lte operators, instead of $between (cf [@ponzao answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb))

Here is an example :

```
const dcr = await Dcr.find({
    "createdAt": {
        "$gte": new Date(currentDate),
        "$lt": new Date(lastDate)
    }
});
```

**EDIT**:

If it still doesn't works, it is probably because your dates are not formatted, maybe you should use a date library, like [moment](https://www.npmjs.com/package/moment), and try like this :

```
const moment = require('moment');
const dcr = await Dcr.find({
    "createdAt": {
        "$gte": new Date(moment(currentDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format()),
        "$lt": new Date(moment(lastDate, 'YYYY/MM/DD').format())
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry for replying late. thank you all for support. its working

Comment: You are welcome ;) Can you mark my answer as resolved ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be better if you use query strings instead of query params for atleast dates. In the route you provided that is :

```
router.get('/smDcr/:currentDate?&:lastDate:', authorize, getDcrBetweenDates);
```

using **?&:** in url to pass 2nd date value will get interpreted as querystring because of (**?**). 
And you are accessing this end point by calling this :

```
http://localhost:3000/smDcr/?currentDate=2019/09/11&?lastDate=2019/09/11
```

In this, **currentDate** will be considered as query string and same is the case with **lastDate**

So I would suggest you to use this instead :

```
router.get('/smDcr', authorize, getDcrBetweenDates);
```

And in your controller, access the values like this :

```
    const lastDate = req.query.lastDate;
    const currentDate = req.query.currentDate;
```

And to access it you should be calling :

```
http://localhost:3000/smDcr?currentDate=2019/09/11&lastDate=2019/09/11
```

Here is a official doc for routing.
[Express Routing](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html)