# Looking for function similar to "BETWEEN" in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql-aggregation

I need to get all records from MongoDB collection `"employee"` where `joining_date` is between `current_date` and `current_date + 5 days`. I couldn't find anything similar to `BETWEEN` operator in `MongoDB` documentation. Below query works fine in Google BigQuery. Looking for similar solution in MongoDB.

```
select * from employee where joining_date BETWEEN current_date() and DATE_ADD(current_date(), interval 5 DAY);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Answer (score 1):

The `$gt` and `$lt` [Comparison Query Operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/) can be used to find matches within a range of dates. Here's one approach.

```
db.employee.find({
    "joining_date": {
        $gt: new Date(),
        $lt: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 5))
    }
})
```