# NodeJS + MongoDB: Show entries after specific date

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date

I have a simple API call to mongoDB that shows me all the entries, it works perfectly and looks like this:

```
   MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) return res.json("Error:Database Connection error" );   
            var dbo = db.db("radar");
            var query = {   };
                dbo.collection("changes").find(query).toArray(function(err, result) {
                    if (err) return res.json("Error:Database error" );   
                    res.json( result );   
                    db.close();
```

After googling, I can't seem to find a query to only show entries after a specific date, or even todays date. Can anybody assist?

JUST FYI, data:

```
 data = {
         "change_number": "CRQ91320s23",
         "change_description": "Nexus work",
         "date": "2/10/2020",
         "changeowner" : "Jeffre Hocking",
         "implementer" : "nathan",}
```

Comment: it's difficult not to find that after googling

Comment: already ask/ans  :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb

Answer (score 1):

Since your `date`-field is of type `String` you will need to convert it to a `Date` in order to be able to correctly compare it to other date values. You can do something like this to find all dates > `2020-10-01` :

```
db.collection('changes').aggregate(
    [{
            $addFields: {
                actualDate: {
                    $dateFromString: {
                        dateString: '$date',
                        format: "%d/%m/%Y"
                    }
                }
            }
        }, {
            $match: {
                actualDate: {
                    $gt: new Date("2020-10-01T00:00:00.000Z")
                }
            }    
        }
    ])
```

It would simplify things if you'd define `date` as an actual `Date` instead of a `String` though.