# Fetch documents using createdAt mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch the documents using createdAt filed in mongodb. Example i want to fetch the documents where today date is equal to createdAt.Attached is the screenshot. In the below case it should return 0.[image]
I have tried using this but it is returning 1.

```
const todayAdded = await InventoryModel.find({
    owner: address, 
    "createdAt" : { 
      $gte: new Date("2016-11-16").toISOString(),
      $lte: new Date("2016-12-01").toISOString() 
    }
  }).estimatedDocumentCount();
```

Comment: Could it be that you need to use an explicit `$and$ in the sub-conjunction, i.e., `createdAt: {$and: [ {$gte: ...}, {$lte: ... } ]}` ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment can you tell me where to add. If possible please add your code in my code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: See the duplicate. Your issue is the same as described in the first answer there. You are doing a string comparison because you converted the date to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: I have seen the problem is `estimatedDocumentCount()` function.

As the [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.estimatedDocumentCount/) explain it will 'Returns the count of all documents in a collection or view'.

I think you expect the `count` from the query, not from the collection.

So, insted of `estimatedDocumentCount()` you have to use `countDocuments()`.
By the way, if you check `todayAdded.length` it should be equal 0.

Try this query:

```js
var result = await model.find({ 
  "owner": "...",
  "createdAt": { 
    "$gte": new Date(2016, 11, 16), 
    "$lt": new Date(2016, 12, 01) 
  }
}).countDocuments(function(err, count) {
      console.log("Number of docs: ", count);
});
```

Comment: oh ya estimatedDocumentCount() returns all results where as countDocuments returns correct results

Comment: Try using ```countDocuments``` instead of ```estimatedDocumentCount```.
Since your problems is not querying the date but returning the total, I've edited the answer.

Comment: Now i am getting 0 always  const todayAdded = await InventoryModel.find({
                owner: address,
                createdAt: {
                  $gte: new Date(2019, 11, 1).toISOString(),
                  $lt: new Date(2019, 11, 3).toISOString(),
                },
              }).countDocuments(); 
It should return 1

Comment: Working fine now Thanks for your answer