# How to filter MongoDb, mongoose DATE

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a date like :

```
{
......
title: x
createdAt:"2021-07-02T11:26:08.671+00:00
......
},
{
......
title: x
createdAt:"2021-07-03T11:26:08.671+00:00
......
},
{
......
title: x
createdAt:"2021-07-05T11:26:08.671+00:00
......
},
```

I want to search data created on 2021-07,year and month matter, how to achieve this? My input date format : 2021-07.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find objects between two dates MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb)

Comment: date is  ""2021-07-05T11:26:08.671+00:00", and my input is 2021-07

Comment: gte 2021-07-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 and lt 2021-08-01T00:00:00.000+00:00 (utc)

Answer (score 0):

You can run the query using `$expr` operator:

```
db.collection.find({$expr: { $and: [
              {
                "$eq": [{"$month": "$createdAt"},7]
              },
              {
                "$eq": [{"$year": "$createdAt"},2021]
              }
          ]})
```