# Compare hour of dates in mongo find method

Tags: mysql, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have mongo documents containing a field createAt date. I would like to search for all documents where

> the hour of createAt at 8  o'clock in the morning of everyday (between 8:00am and 8:00am)

, but I have no clue how to write the query.

In MySQL I can write it like this:

```
select * from table where hour（createAt）= 8
```

[image: document in collection]

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`$hour`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/hour/) with [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/).

```
db.collection.find({
  $expr: {
    $eq: [
      {
        $hour: "$createdAt"
      },
      8
    ]
  }
})
```

[Sample Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rIElsRhxYGs)

Answer (score 0):

Your question has already been [resolved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943222/find-objects-between-two-dates-mongodb).

I wrote you an example on the [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Cbp0AME-L4M).