# I'm trying to get new records from a collection using pymongo

Tags: pymongo

I want to get new elements added to a MongoDB collection within the last 24 hours.
My scripts are in Python so I'm using pymongo library.

I've tried:
`yesterday_datetime = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1) # datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 2, 10, 53, 47, 667989)`
`collection.find_one({"DbCreateDate": {'gt': yesterday_datetime}})`
But the output is:
`None`

I know there is a new element. When I do:
`collection.find_one({"DbCreateDate": datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 3, 0, 0)})`
It outputs:
`{'_id': 'FAKE_01', 'DbCreateDate': datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 3, 0, 0)}`

I've also tried
`collection.find_one({"DbCreateDate": {'gt': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 31, 0, 0)}})`
`collection.find_one({"DbCreateDate": {'gte': datetime.datetime(2022, 1, 1, 0, 0)}})`
`collection.find_one({"DbCreateDate": {'gt': datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 31, 0, 0).isoformat()}})`
Always output None.

Comment: What does `collection.find_one` without any filter return? What is the format of the stored value? If it is a string, gt will not work!

Comment: collection.find_one without any filter returns 
`{'_id': 'FAKE_01', 'DbCreateDate': datetime.datetime(2020, 4, 6, 0, 0)}`

The output is a dictionary and the value of the DbCreateDate key is a datetime.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2943685/5962841 - I think you need to serialize it in a specific way :)

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

I needed to add a **$** when creating the filter, before *gt*:

```
collection.find_one({"DbCreateDate": {'$gt': yesterday_datetime}})
```