# Using type of a date field as string in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In `Mongoose/MongoDB Schema` if I use `type` of **created_at** field as `String` instead of `Date`, will it increase the time taken by my query when I fetch my results sorted according to `created_at` field or not? Also will there be any other significant performance issues if I use `String` but not `Date`?

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: why would you want to?

Comment: I have some documents already storing `created_at` field as `String` that's why i thought if there won't be any problem then will keep it as it is.

Comment: you won't be able to query on date / time if it's stored as a string

Comment: which type of query you are talking about. Also i am calling my documents based on sorted order of this `created_at` field but it is working fine AFAIK(but not sure that's why i asked this question).

Comment: what do the dates (in string format) look like in your documents?

Comment: `"2017-05-16T02:08:48.419+05:30"`

Comment: The reason you're seeing sorting working is because `2017-05-16T02:08:48.419+05:30` is > `2016-05-16T02:08:48.419+05:30` (sorted a-z as a string)
I would always store dates, as dates, however.

Comment: Yes I know that's why in the first place I didn't think there will be any problem, sorting was working fine. But now this point came to my mind and I want to know will there be any problem or not ??

Comment: if all you're doing is sorting like that, there won't be a problem. You won't however, be able to query for documents with a date 'in range' - for example between two dates

Comment: @Alex By using $gt and $lt I can still use my `created_at` field to find documents between two dates.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Query the string type Date in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314271/query-the-string-type-date-in-mongodb)

Comment: @Alex thanks, Acc to your post if the user wanted to fetch results modified a day before then he can get them by using $gt and and for comparing time he can use Date.now() and from that Date.now() he can use previous date. like if current date is `"2017-05-16T02:08:48.419+05:30"` then he will write the query `db.collection.find({"createdAt" : { $gte : new ISODate("2017-05-15T02:08:48.419+05:30") }});`

Comment: @Alex are you there ??

Comment: yes, that's right